# @font-face css not working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm having trouble with an @font-face declaration and I'm hoping someone can tell me what the problem is.

Here's my @font-face CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MuseoSlab500';
src: url('fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
     url('fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.svg#webfontyumMOUTD') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

My font files are all in a folder in the root of my site called 'fonts'. The stylesheet and the html file (it's a one page site) are in the root. I'm looking at the @font-face and it looks no different than declarations I'ved before yet for some reason this one is not working. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: can you post your link to your site?

Comment: Normally I'd bet it was a pathing issue, but from the way you've described it, that doesn't seem like it'd be the case.

Comment: I have the page posted at http://www.odysseydesignstudio.com/lab/manifesto/

I thought it might be a path issue too, but I looked repeatedly and even tried rearranging the files and changing paths to get it to work and nothing was successful. They don't work when I test them locally either (using file// protocol). I thought maybe the font files were corrupted so I used another set of files for the same font and it still didn't work, so I think it must be a code thing, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Can you tell me where? I'm looking at the file and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I figured it out. There's a comment on line 56 that uses html comment syntax and not css syntax. It's causing a parsing error with the css so the font-face tags were being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I always put my web fonts folder inside my CSS folder like this:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'CartoGothicStd-Bold';
    src: url('@font-face/CartoStd-Bold.eot');
    src: url('@font-face/CartoStd-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('@font-face/CartoStd-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('@font-face/CartoStd-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('@font-face/CartoStd-Bold.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

My folder is called @font-face. Give it a go...see if you get the fonts working.

I just noticed you're missing `}`

Comment: It's bad practice to use symbols like `@` in folder names.

Comment: In the code here, yes, but I checked his CSS file and there it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .otf file instead of .ttf

I had also faced this problem. I got it working by replacing to .otf file.